# describe the equivalence classes of ≈

Tags: proof-writing, equivalence-relations

Here is the question itself.

Suppose that ∼ and ≈ are two equivalence relations on the same set A. Assume that there are at least two equivalence classes for ∼. Suppose that any two elements which are different equivalence classes for ∼ are in the same equivalence class for ≈. As completely as possible, describe the equivalence classes of ≈, and prove your description is correct.

I know how to proof for equivalence class for ∼, that is to show reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. And to proof for ≈, I can proof bijective function. But for this question, I just confused on what it's asking and how should I continue.

Comment: Try an example: let $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and say that $\sim$ gives two equivalence classes $\{a\}$ and $\{b,c,d\}$. What does the assumption "any two elements which are different equivalence classes for $\sim$ are in the same equivalence class for $\approx$" tell us about which elements are equivalent by $\approx$ in $A$? What about the case that $\sim$ gives two equivalence classes $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$?

Comment: To elaborate on the hint in case it wasn't clear enough, suppose $x,y\in A$ and suppose that $x\nsim y$ (*that $x$ is not related to $y$ according to the first equivalence relation*).  Does this imply that $x\approx y$?  Now... suppose instead that $x\sim y$.  Does this imply that $x\approx y$?  Are you sure?  So then... at the end of the day, we have that every $x,y$ we could have chosen we must have that $x\approx y$, yes?  What are the equivalence classes for $\approx$ then?